# Selecting rows with max attribute value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've the following table
[image]

and I want to come up with the following table [image]

What I want is to select rows with largest  version of each client. Tahnks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * From Table1 T
         JOIN (SELECT clientid,Max(version) As MVer 
               From Table1 Group By clientid) S
         ON T.clientid = S.clientid And T.version  = S.MVer
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/affd8/5)**

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 
(
select *,rn=Dense_rank()over(partition by Clientid order by version desc) from table
)x
where x.rn=1
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b1e09/1)

Comment: see demo @SherzodMuminov